# AutoMapper property with TypeName start with Tbl in Source and property start with FK in destination

Tags: automapper

i have problem with automapper for convert property with TypeName start with Tbl in Source and property start with FK in destination, but this error occured:
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Tbl_Child -> Int32  Tbl_Child -> System.Int32 Destination path: Destination.FK_Child.FK_Child Source value: Tbl_Child

code is:

```
public class Source
{
    public Tbl_Child Child { get; set; }

    public string SourceName { get; set; }
}

public class Tbl_Child
{
    public int ID_Child { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public int FK_Child { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public string SourceName { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var src = new Source()
        {
            Child = new Tbl_Child()
                {
                    ChildName = "ch",
                    ID_Child = 1
                },
            SourceName = "src"
        };

    AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
    var dest = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(src);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

i test AutoMapper version 2.0.0.0, and 3.1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Automapper is able to map properties with the same name and [flattening](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Flattening) in properties. For other properties you must specify the mapping that you want.

For example mapping from `Source.Child.ID_Child` to `Destination.FK_Child` would be accomplished like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ForMember(d => d.FK_Child, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Child.ID_Child));
```

And you can chain all your custom mappings like so

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ForMember(d => d.FK_Child, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Child.ID_Child))
.ForMember(d => d.ChildName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Child.ChildName));
```

This mapping should be enough in this case but I think you may need to [read the wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) a bit before going on

Comment: my problem not convert, my problem is error that raise please check my code and run, occur error, why?

Comment: Please reread the answer; you have the error because you need to specify the mappings on properties that either differ between source and destination or cannot be flattened between the two

Comment: i read your comment, but i want only flat property convert, what error automapper, plz run code, i get error, my problem not logical, my problem is runtime.

Comment: I'm sorry @MohammadAkbari I don't understand what your problem is when you say that you want a flat property convert. I ran your code, told you how to correct the mapping and tested it again to check that it works. Perhaps you could restate your problem

Comment: in my code i want only src.SourceName convert to dest.SourceName and other properti in dest desfault.